# RegEx in Xcode to Match Beginning Phrase

Tags: regex, xcode

I have the following bit of code:

```
CGFloat eyeBallColorComponents[4] = //some stuff that changes
```

I'd simply like to match any expression that has `CGFloat eyeBallColorComponents[4] =` at the beginning of it no matter what is to the right of the equal sign. I'm using the `XCode` regular expression find and replace. Anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CGFloat eyeBallColorComponents\[4\] =.*
```

The `.*` matches any characters up to the end of the line.
The `\` is the escape character.

Comment: Thanks. Possible you could edit the ^ out of your post, for whatever reason in xCode it didn't work with that ^.

Comment: @StackOverFlowRider : Removed the ^. Now the regex matches anywhere in a line.